# DataTables.net Excel export returns no results in Progressive Web App

Tags: javascript, excel, datatables, export, progressive-web-apps

I've implemented the [Excel export](https://datatables.net/reference/button/) functionality of the DataTables in my Progressive Web Application. It is working fine in mobile web browser when I'm trying to access my website directly using URL (both iOS & Android). But when I try to use it inside my app (PWA), it doesn't work.

Note: I've included only html5 buttons

**iOS:** It displays a blank page.
**Android:** Nothing happens.

```
var dt = $("#dt-table").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "GetTableInfo"           
    },
    "buttons": [
        {
            "extend": "excelHtml5",
            "className": "btn-sm btn-primary",
            "text": "Export",
            "title": "Weekly Report",
            "exportOptions": {
                "columns": [0,2,3,4,5,6]
            }
        }
    ],
    .....
```

Comment: There is more information if you read further into the documentation, like [**this page**](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excel).

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into it. In my case, the excel export is not working only when triggered within the PWA app.